# Rails 7 asset pipeline missing bits?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

In development, the application behaves as expected.  However when deploying to production, the log complains about:
`ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "dfull" is not present in the asset pipeline.`

However, when looking at the application's files the file is present

```
cd /current/public/assets
ls -al df*
$  dfull-7c187c14af3a8d29e060e48047ead45a136397c74d0208519e6d128c1097a283.png
```

How can this situation be ironed out?

Comment: Try `dfull.png` instead of `dfull`.

Comment: Maybe try clobbering and recompiling the assets. What is the code used to reference the picture?

Comment: Yes, that was what was done to effectively solve the issue, in addition to naming the image shortcut with the file extension; there was also an asset with the same name but with an svg extension & that might have confused rails.  Cleanup, naming, clobbering and re-compiling solved it.